# C compiler omits code, gives no errors

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

I was doing the pointers exercise from "Learn C the Hard Way" and one of the extra credits is to print the loops in reverse order, anyway, I was toying around trying to get the exercise right and I came up with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // create two arrays we care about
    int ages[] = {23, 43, 12, 89, 2};
    char *names[] = {
        "Alan", "Frank",
        "Mary", "John", "Lisa"
    };
    // safely get the size of ages
    int count = sizeof(ages) / sizeof(int);

    // set up the pointers to the start of the arrays
    int *cur_age = ages;
    char **cur_name = names;

    // fourth way with pointers in a stupid complex way
    for(cur_name = names, cur_age = ages; (ages - cur_age) >= count;
        cur_name--, cur_age--){
        printf("%s lived %d years so far.\n", *cur_name, *cur_age);
    }
    printf("---\n");

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("%d\n", i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me neither warnings nor errors! Skips the weird for-loop and prints the last loop. What's wrong with this code? Thank you.

Comment: what error did you expected to see ?

Comment: Whats this suppose to do `(ages - cur_age) >= count;` ? Do you know ?

Comment: Any kind of error, doesn't matter, What I think is odd is that it gives no output whatsoever.

Comment: `for(cur_name = names, cur_age = ages;` this starts at the beginning instead of at the end. That's why it terminates immediately - it's already home.

Comment: Oh, what a dunce I am, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(ages - cur_age)` is equal to zero at the start of the loop, so your loop condition `(ages - cur_age) >= count` is never satisfied.  Furthermore, using the decrement operators will result in undefined behavior, as you are starting from the first element of each array already.

Comment: The intention was to start at the end and print in reverse. Fails when it doesn't find the correct starting point.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
// Let cur_age point to the last element of the array.
// Same with cur_name.
int *cur_age = ages + count - 1;
char **cur_name = names + count - 1;

for(; (ages - cur_age) >= 0; cur_name--, cur_age--){
```